# C# do this statement first then

Tags: c#, insert-update

I have face the problem with

```
{
   double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
   double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
   textBox8.Text = (a + b).ToString();
   textBox1.Text = "";
   double c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
   double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text);
   textBox9.Text = (c + d).ToString();
   textBox2.Text = "";
}


//cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Table1 set balance='" + textBox8 + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox13.Text + "','" + textBox14.Text + "', where ID=" + textBox15.Text, con);
  cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = ? " + " WHERE ID = ?", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUT", textBox8.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUT", textBox9.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", textBox15.Text);

  con.Open();

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  con.Close();
  loaddata();
}
```

I have 2 `textbox`, one is Balance, one is IN

the Balance is loaddata from my database, the IN is allowed user to key in a value so

`IN + Balance = Balance`, and this will update to the database.

The Update function is work prefect. but how can i add the value first and then run the update ? advise.

Comment: what actually  you want to do ?

Answer (score 2):

since you are doing this

```
textBox8.Text = (a + b).ToString();
textBox9.Text = (c + d).ToString();
```

that means, sum is with the `textBox8.Text` and `textBox9.Text`

then you are doing this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUT", textBox8.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OUT", textBox9.Text);
```

and your query is :

```
UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = textbox8.Text  WHERE ID = x
UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = textbox9.Text  WHERE ID = x
```

there for, when you do `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, your column `OUT` in row with `ID` x in the `Table1` gets updated twice,

first, its value is set to Text of `textbox8` and then it gets updated to that of `textbox9`.

I guess, this is not what you want.

You might want to do it in a loop, for different IDs (i.e. different rows) i.e.

```
 UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = textbox8.Text WHERE ID = x1
 UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = textbox9.Text WHERE ID = x2
```

or

same ID but different columns i.e.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET OUT = textbox8.Text, AnotherColumn=textbox9.Text  WHERE ID = x
```